# Why setState could not restate the widget class

Tags: setstate, playing-cards

I have written the code for card game trying to show the cards using the Playing card library and, having created the show player hand in the widget class, it could show the cards in a good orders at static stage. However, when I tried to deal card and add additional card to the List (i.e. hand), and setState, it was not update the screening accordingly. Can anyone help?

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  Games _game = Games();
  int _counter = 0;
  List<Kar> desk = [];
  List<Kar> remainingDesk = [];
  Kar _drawnCard;
  double _avgCounter = 0;
  ShapeBorder shape = RoundedRectangleBorder(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
      side: BorderSide(color: Colors.black, width: 1));
  List<Kar> _playerA = [
    Kar(suit: 1, rank: 14),
    Kar(suit: 1, rank: 11),
  ];
  List<Kar> _dealer = [
    Kar(suit: 2, rank: 12),
    Kar(suit: 3, rank: 13),
  ];
  List<Kar> _blackJack = [
    Kar(suit: 1, rank: 14),
    Kar(suit: 1, rank: 11),
    Kar(suit: 3, rank: 13),
  ];
  double _cardSize = 0;
  bool _selected = false;
  bool _second = false;
  bool _playerTurn = false;
  bool _dealerTurn = false;
  bool _playerTurnEnd = false;
  bool _dealerTurnEnd = false;
  int _handScore = 0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    Games _games = Games();
    setState(() {
      desk = createDesk();
      remainingDesk = List.from(desk);
    });
    _incrementCounter();
    super.initState();
  }

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: Container(
          width: 300,
          height: 580,
          child: Stack(
            children: [
              PlayerHand(player: false, hand: _playerA),
              Text('Score: ' + _handScore.toString()),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: () {
            Kar _drawnCard = drawCardfromDesk(remainingDesk);
              setState(() {
                _handScore += _drawnCard.rank;
                _playerA.add(_drawnCard);

              });
            });
          },
               tooltip: 'Increment',
          child: Icon(Icons
              .add)), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }

  List<Kar> createDesk() {
    List<Kar> desk = [];
    for (int _rank = 2; _rank < 15; _rank++) {
      for (int _suit = 1; _suit < 5; _suit++) {
        desk.add(Kar(suit: _suit, rank: _rank));
      }
      ;
    }
    ;
    return desk;
  }

  Kar drawCardfromDesk(List<Kar> desk) {
    Kar _dealCard;
    var rng = new Random();
    _dealCard = desk[rng.nextInt(desk.length)];
    desk.remove(_dealCard);
    return _dealCard;
  }
}


import 'dart:convert';

import 'dart:io';

import 'package:blackjack/main.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:playing_cards/playing_cards.dart';


class PlayerHand extends StatefulWidget {
  List<Kar> hand;
  bool player= false;
  BuildContext context;


  PlayerHand({
    @required this.hand,
    @required this.player
  });

  @override
  _PlayerHandState createState() => _PlayerHandState();
}

class _PlayerHandState extends State<PlayerHand> {
  int _handLength=0;
  bool _player= false;
  ShapeBorder shape = RoundedRectangleBorder(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
      side: BorderSide(color: Colors.black, width: 1));




@override
  void initState() {
    //var authBloc = Provider.of<AuthBloc>(context);
    // TODO: implement initState
    setState(() {
      _handLength = widget.hand.length;
      _player = widget.player;
    });
    

    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //final authBloc = Provider.of<AuthBloc>(context);
    

    return _handLength==0
    ?Container()
    : _handLength ==1
    ? Container(
        child: PlayingCardView(
          card: PlayingCard(
              suitsName[widget.hand[0].suit], cardValue[widget.hand[0].rank]),
          showBack: false,
          shape: shape,
        ),
      )
    : _handLength ==2
    ? Container(
      child:Container(
                  height: 180,
                  width: 380,
                 // duration: Duration(seconds: 1),
                  child: FlatCardFan(children: [
                    PlayingCardView(
                        card: PlayingCard(suitsName[widget.hand[0].suit],
                            cardValue[widget.hand[0].rank]),
                        showBack: _player?true:false,
                        elevation: 3.0,
                        shape: shape),
                    PlayingCardView(
                        card: PlayingCard(suitsName[widget.hand[1].suit],
                            cardValue[widget.hand[1].rank]),
                        //showBack: true,
                        elevation: 3.0,
                        shape: shape),
                  ]))
    )
    : _handLength ==3
    ? Container(
      child:Container(
                  height: 180,
                  width: 380,
                  //duration: Duration(seconds: 1),
                  child: FlatCardFan(children: [
                    PlayingCardView(
                        card: PlayingCard(suitsName[widget.hand[0].suit],
                            cardValue[widget.hand[0].rank]),
                        showBack: _player?true:false,
                        elevation: 3.0,
                        shape: shape),
                    PlayingCardView(
                        card: PlayingCard(suitsName[widget.hand[1].suit],
                            cardValue[widget.hand[1].rank]),
                        //showBack: true,
                        elevation: 3.0,
                        shape: shape),
                        PlayingCardView(
                        card: PlayingCard(suitsName[widget.hand[2].suit],
                            cardValue[widget.hand[2].rank]),
                        //showBack: true,
                        elevation: 3.0,
                        shape: shape),
                  ]))
    ): _handLength ==4
    ? Container(
      child:Container(
                  height: 180,
                  width: 300,
                 // duration: Duration(seconds: 1),
                  child: FlatCardFan(children: [
                    PlayingCardView(
                        card: PlayingCard(suitsName[widget.hand[0].suit],
                            cardValue[widget.hand[0].rank]),
                        showBack: _player?true:false,
                        elevation: 3.0,
                        shape: shape),
                    PlayingCardView(
                        card: PlayingCard(suitsName[widget.hand[1].suit],
                            cardValue[widget.hand[1].rank]),
                        //showBack: true,
                        elevation: 3.0,
                        shape: shape),
                    PlayingCardView(
                        card: PlayingCard(suitsName[widget.hand[2].suit],
                            cardValue[widget.hand[2].rank]),
                        //showBack: true,
                        elevation: 3.0,
                        shape: shape),
                    PlayingCardView(
                        card: PlayingCard(suitsName[widget.hand[3].suit],
                            cardValue[widget.hand[3].rank]),
                        //showBack: true,
                        elevation: 3.0,
                        shape: shape),
                  ]))
    ): _handLength ==5
    ? Container(
      child:AnimatedContainer(
                  height: 180,
                  width: 300,
                  duration: Duration(seconds: 1),
                  child: FlatCardFan(children: [
                    PlayingCardView(
                        card: PlayingCard(suitsName[widget.hand[0].suit],
                            cardValue[widget.hand[0].rank]),
                        showBack: _player?true:false,
                        elevation: 3.0,
                        shape: shape),
                    PlayingCardView(
                        card: PlayingCard(suitsName[widget.hand[1].suit],
                            cardValue[widget.hand[1].rank]),
                        //showBack: true,
                        elevation: 3.0,
                        shape: shape),
                    PlayingCardView(
                        card: PlayingCard(suitsName[widget.hand[2].suit],
                            cardValue[widget.hand[2].rank]),
                        //showBack: true,
                        elevation: 3.0,
                        shape: shape),
                    PlayingCardView(
                        card: PlayingCard(suitsName[widget.hand[3].suit],
                            cardValue[widget.hand[3].rank]),
                        //showBack: true,
                        elevation: 3.0,
                        shape: shape),
                      PlayingCardView(
                        card: PlayingCard(suitsName[widget.hand[4].suit],
                            cardValue[widget.hand[4].rank]),
                        //showBack: true,
                        elevation: 3.0,
                        shape: shape),
                  ]))
    ) : _handLength ==6
    ?Container(
      child:AnimatedContainer(
                  height: 180,
                  width: 300,
                  duration: Duration(seconds: 1),
                  child: FlatCardFan(children: [
                    PlayingCardView(
                        card: PlayingCard(suitsName[widget.hand[0].suit],
                            cardValue[widget.hand[0].rank]),
                        showBack: _player?true:false,
                        elevation: 3.0,
                        shape: shape),
                    PlayingCardView(
                        card: PlayingCard(suitsName[widget.hand[1].suit],
                            cardValue[widget.hand[1].rank]),
                        //showBack: true,
                        elevation: 3.0,
                        shape: shape),
                    PlayingCardView(
                        card: PlayingCard(suitsName[widget.hand[2].suit],
                            cardValue[widget.hand[2].rank]),
                        //showBack: true,
                        elevation: 3.0,
                        shape: shape),
                    PlayingCardView(
                        card: PlayingCard(suitsName[widget.hand[3].suit],
                            cardValue[widget.hand[3].rank]),
                        //showBack: true,
                        elevation: 3.0,
                        shape: shape),
                      PlayingCardView(
                        card: PlayingCard(suitsName[widget.hand[4].suit],
                            cardValue[widget.hand[4].rank]),
                        //showBack: true,
                        elevation: 3.0,
                        shape: shape),
                      PlayingCardView(
                        card: PlayingCard(suitsName[widget.hand[5].suit],
                            cardValue[widget.hand[5].rank]),
                        //showBack: true,
                        elevation: 3.0,
                        shape: shape),
                  ]))
    )
    : Container(
      child:AnimatedContainer(
                  height: 180,
                  width: 300,
                  duration: Duration(seconds: 1),
                  child: FlatCardFan(children: [
                    PlayingCardView(
                        card: PlayingCard(suitsName[widget.hand[0].suit],
                            cardValue[widget.hand[0].rank]),
                        showBack: _player?true:false,
                        elevation: 3.0,
                        shape: shape),
                    PlayingCardView(
                        card: PlayingCard(suitsName[widget.hand[1].suit],
                            cardValue[widget.hand[1].rank]),
                        //showBack: true,
                        elevation: 3.0,
                        shape: shape),
                    PlayingCardView(
                        card: PlayingCard(suitsName[widget.hand[2].suit],
                            cardValue[widget.hand[2].rank]),
                        //showBack: true,
                        elevation: 3.0,
                        shape: shape),
                    PlayingCardView(
                        card: PlayingCard(suitsName[widget.hand[3].suit],
                            cardValue[widget.hand[3].rank]),
                        //showBack: true,
                        elevation: 3.0,
                        shape: shape),
                      PlayingCardView(
                        card: PlayingCard(suitsName[widget.hand[4].suit],
                            cardValue[widget.hand[4].rank]),
                        //showBack: true,
                        elevation: 3.0,
                        shape: shape),
                      PlayingCardView(
                        card: PlayingCard(suitsName[widget.hand[5].suit],
                            cardValue[widget.hand[5].rank]),
                        //showBack: true,
                        elevation: 3.0,
                        shape: shape),
                        PlayingCardView(
                        card: PlayingCard(suitsName[widget.hand[6].suit],
                            cardValue[widget.hand[6].rank]),
                        //showBack: true,
                        elevation: 3.0,
                        shape: shape),
                  ])));

  }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Build your widget dynamically :

```
FlatCardFan( 
           children: List.generate(widget.hand.length, (index) =>  
                PlayingCardView(
                    card: PlayingCard(suitsName[widget.hand[index].suit],
                        cardValue[widget.hand[0].rank]),
                    showBack: _player?true:false,
                    elevation: 3.0,
                    shape: shape
                   ),
                ),
             ),
```

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: ════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════
Offset argument contained a NaN value.
'dart:ui/painting.dart':
Failed assertion: line 40: '<optimized out>'

Comment: The card was displayed correctly, but some error codes shown on the debug console as above

Comment: you have set _handLength = widget.hand.length in initstate; and check _handLength == 0, and so on, but when you add a value on hand list, you didn't update _handLength, better to check _handLength condition dynamically when draw widgets.

Comment: Thanks shorol, I have removed the init state and let the widget work dynamically as suggested. It works well.

Comment: Besides, the error for Nan should be related to the playing card function that it the FlatCardFan would have error when the hand length is 1. I added an condition to show the PlayingCardView instead of the FlatCardFan, and it worked fine.